# stop refreshing polymer page with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, polymer-1.0

I would like to know how polymer stops anchor refreshing behavior at the same domain but it does not stop when using  `window.location.*` .

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please check the help menu about how to ask good questions. It's quite unclear what this question is about.

Comment: I'm sorry for ambiguity but I'm asking for my code that when I use `window.location.href` for lets say a button `on-click`, the page is refreshing but when using anchor tag it's not so I had to wrap every button with anchor tag to achieve the desired behavior which is non refreshing

Comment: Are you talking about app-router?

Comment: no it's something like [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page) and I want to know how polymer do this , to change address by JavaScript without reloading  the page

Comment: I'm sure Polymer doesn't do anything like that. If anchor tags only change the part after `#`, thab it's normal browser behavior that the page is not reloaded.

Comment: but in [link](https://github.com/PolymerElements/polymer-starter-kit/blob/master/app/index.html#L85) for example.  I know that the page's data is based on `data-route` but why it didn't redirect to `href` address and refresh the page Although the 'baseUrl' has no `#`

Comment: Then https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API is used.